# How to test event listener in spring-boot

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I am trying to test an event listener like this one

```
@Component
class EventHandler {
     @EventListener
    fun handler(event: SomeEvent) {      //SomeEvent is has properties source and someObject
        ...
    }
}
```

My test is in this format

```
@SpringBootTest
class SendWelcomeEmailTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var publisher: ApplicationEventPublisher
    
    @Test
    fun test(){
        val someObject = SomeObject()
        val event = SomeEvent(this, someObject)
        val listener = mockkClass(EventHandler::class)

        publisher.publishEvent(event)
        verify { listener.handler(any()) }
    }
}
```

When I run this test I am getting an

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: EventHandler(#4).handler(matcher<SomeEvent>())) was not called
```

error, however by using debugger I can see that `handler` function is entered with correct parameters. So why doesn't verify catch the execution of `handler` function?

Comment: I can, but the whole point is to test the handler with an event (to test the flow). At least, that's what is required from me

Comment: I mean this is an oversimplified version. The real example uses kafka so I think it's necessary to also test that correct events are caught by the handler

Comment: The (only) problem seems to be in `mockkClass()`!? Please show/[edit]!

Comment: My friend, if you don't know the answer to my original question just ignore this post

Comment: @xerx593 I didn't really understand what you said, to be honest. Show/edit what?

Comment: Ok, found (what is mockkClass:). Have you tried [springmockk](https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk)? (It is also referenced by mockk doc, in chapter "spring support", https://mockk.io/#spring-support)

Comment: @Jens ok I won't if you don't want to, but in the future please be more like xerx593 or jhyot and try to help solve the problem instead of bending it to your solution. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with [springmockk](https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk):

> Gradle:

> ```
> testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.1.1")
> ```

> Maven:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>  <groupId>com.ninja-squad</groupId>
>  <artifactId>springmockk</artifactId>
>  <version>3.1.1</version>
>  <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

This test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SendWelcomeEmailTest {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var publisher: ApplicationEventPublisher
  @MockkBean(relaxed = true)// strict by default!
  private lateinit var listenerMock: EventHandler
  @Test
  fun test() {
    
    val someObject = SomeObject()
    val event = SomeEvent(this, someObject)
    
    publisher.publishEvent(event)

    verify { listenerMock.handler(any()) }
  }
}
```

..should pass!

Please also consider:

> If you want to make sure Mockito (and the standard MockBean and SpyBean annotations) is not used, you can also exclude the mockito dependency:

> `testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") { exclude(module = "mockito-core")}`

...limitations, compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just because you call `mockkClass(EventHandler::class)`, the bean registered in the Spring container does not magically get replaced by your local mock.
The original bean is still called (as you verified using the debugger), and your local mock does not participate in the Spring container.

In general, you can use `@MockBean` from Spring (check the Javadocs for details), which will create a Mockito mock *and* register it in the Spring container, replacing the original bean (this is done behind the scenes by the Spring Test Framework).

But I think in your case that might not work, because the bean will probably not be registered as an event handler, but you could try.

If `@MockBean` does not work, the only option I see is to explicitly declare a hand-made "mock" `EventHandler` subclass and mark it with `@Primary`, so that it gets chosen over the original one by Spring. Then you can add any verification method you like there (e.g. in the mock `handler` method, save events that arrive into a local state, and add a method to read the recorded state).